# Windows Phone SDK for AR, location chat?

Tags: windows-phone-7, augmented-reality, quickblox

Hi I'm building a social networking / dating app where users can see who is around in Augmented Reality mode.
To speed things up I need:

1. Server / API to store users' locations
2. AR lib or SDK to do client-side integration

I've done some research on this, there is GART library for WP7: [Implementing augmented reality using GART](http://igrali.com/2012/05/24/implementing-augmented-reality-using-gart/) and code samples from MSDN: [Augmented Reality Motion Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Sensors)

I'm also considering using Quickblox SDK as they have done exactly what I need - AR Chat - but for iPhone - so I'm thinking of taking their WP7 Location Chat code sample [QuickBlox Developers (API docs, code samples, SDK)](http://quickblox.com/developers/SuperSample_%28Map_Chat_code_sample%29_Windows_8_%28WP7%29) and doing AR part myself with GART library or from scratch using MSDN samples.

Have looked into Wikitude Architect as well but they do it via web/Javascript overlay so not native which I don't really like.

Any suggestions regarding what's the best approach to implement AR Chat on WP7 - are there any better solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Server / API to store users' locations

I think QuickBlox is good solution for this purpose. There is VK Radar sample application http://quickblox.com/augmented-reality-chat-for-mobile-applications/ wich demonstrates that QuickBlox is good solution for AR based applications.

> 1. AR lib or SDK to do client-side integration

I recomende to use GART. This is great kit, it has 2 samples http://gart.codeplex.com/documentation : SimpleAR & BingAR . I used them when develop simple application at one hackathon some times ago